# Composite pattern confuses me

Tags: design-patterns

I have a few different types of validator classes that i am using at the moment all implementing a validator interface.  Occasionally i require combinations of them but usually i need them individually.  Does this sound like a good situation to use the composite pattern?

Answer (score 7):

Could be, based on the minimal information you provide.

You could implement a Validator which contains a collection of other validators, and uses all of the child validators to validate the given data.

As an extension/alternative, you could also implement logical operations via this pattern, e.g. Validators which AND / OR / XOR etc. the result of two (or more) child validators.